# Can I add my own root-level bookmark groups in Firefox via an add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Firefox comes with three top-level bookmark groups: Bookmarks Toolbar, Bookmarks Menu, and Unsorted Bookmarks. You can see the three groups by clicking "Show All Bookmarks" on the "Bookmarks" menu.

I am working on a Firefox add-on and would like to add a new type of root-level bookmark category. By using the built-in bookmark system to store bookmarks for my add-on, the add-on can take advantage of a familiar interface and tools like Firefox Sync. The use cases for the add-on make more sense if the add-on's bookmarks are stored separately from the user's traditional bookmarks. That is to say, I want to create a new group alongside the built-in "Bookmarks Toolbar," "Bookmarks Menu," and "Unsorted Bookmarks," and store my bookmarks in this new group.

[image: Built-in bookmark groups in Firefox]

I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples that demonstrate if adding a new top-level bookmark category is possible. Can anyone say if this is possible and, if it is not, why this isn't allowed?

Comment: I can say, with a high level of confidence, that it is doable. However, it is vague to me what "stored separately" means. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @paa I am working on an add-on that provides a unique method of visiting bookmarks. Where the Bookmarks Menu is a place to store infrequently visited sites and the Bookmarks Toolbar is a place to store frequently visited sites, this new group will be used for sites that are visited usually once daily, like news websites. The add-on will provide a way to quickly rotate through these sites. The add-on's sites are currently stored within a sub-group under the "Bookmarks Menu" group. This will work -- it just seemed like creating your own root-level group would be possible. Appreciate your help.

Comment: As I see it, what you need is to open the Library window focused to a specific folder. Is that ok? Because root folders (other than the builtins) come with weird restrictions, e.g. their bookmarks are neither discoverable through the search box nor accounted for most/recently visited.

Comment: That'll work. Having my own bookmarks root folder would keep my app's bookmarks separate from the user's, but it's not a hard  requirement. Thanks for your help. If you want to put your comment in the form of an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of root folders is possible, but Places UI does not treat them as equals to the built-ins.

If you want, you can open the Library focused to a specific folder

```js
var myfolderid; // the id returned by createFolder or otherwise obtained
PlacesCommandHook.showPlacesOrganizer(myfolderid);
```

Code not running in the context of ChromeWindow should get a reference to one. For Add-on SDK extension that would be something like

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
getMostRecentBrowserWindow().PlacesCommandHook.showPlacesOrganizer(myfolderid);
```